# select div by id using vanilla JS instead of JQuery $ selector to apply Raphaeljs method

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, dom, raphael

I'm using **RaphaelJs' mousedown()** method. The problem is, I want to apply mousedown() on div which is being selected using **$(id)** selector of JQuery. I want to use vanilla Js for it because I don't want to use Jquery for some performance reasons.
(See code [on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapil_sarwat/xz28kc96/37/)).

I tried **document.getElementById()** method, but the object returned by it is not compatible with **RaphaelJs' mousedown()** method

can anyone suggest me any way to get this done?

```
let idRaw = document.getElementById('canvas');
let id = '#canvas';

/**
* I want idRaw.mousedown(...); instead of $(id).mousedown(...);
* to know more check the jsFiddle link above
*/

$(id).mousedown(...);
$(id).mousemove(...);
$(id).mouseup(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
idRaw.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    // Your code
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define event callbacks like below-

```
idRaw.onmouseover = function (e) {
     // your code of mouse over event handler
};
```

Please refer the documentation https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp